# Linux keyboard event capturing /dev/inputX

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I was trying to capture keyboard events.
e.g. I want to drill down a keylogger from the scratch.
After 2 hours of fighting I found the following

```
neel@pc1$ ls -l /dev/input/by-id
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 2010-05-05 21:33 usb-Plus_More_Enterprise_LTD._USB-compliant_keyboard-event-kbd -> ../event1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 2010-05-05 21:33 usb-Plus_More_Enterprise_LTD._USB-compliant_keyboard-event-mouse -> ../event2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 2010-05-05 21:33 usb-Plus_More_Enterprise_LTD._USB-compliant_keyboard-mouse -> ../mouse1
```

But when I tried to

```
neel@pc1$ sudo cat /dev/input/usb-Plus_More_Enterprise_LTD._USB-compliant_keyboard-event-kbd
```

It yields nothing
THERE WAS NO OUTPUT

after a bit more searching Now I am thinking probabbly something in Xorg blocks it.

So Any more Information ??
and atthe end of the say how can I read the input from that file ??
or is there any other way of capturing keyboard events ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for the clue about `ls -l /dev/input/by-id` it helped me a lot !.

```
defenderdz@defenderdz-pc:~$ ls -l /dev/input/by-id | grep kbd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 nov.  28 14:04 usb-Logitech_USB_Receiver-event-kbd -> ../event7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 nov.  29 00:33 usb-NOVATEK_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd -> ../event26
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 nov.  28 14:04 usb-SONiX_USB_DEVICE-event-kbd -> ../event3
defenderdz@defenderdz-pc:~$
```

'kbd' is the suffix used for keyboard devices (I have 3 keyboards connected).

Your error is that you're accessing the **wrong folder** :

`/dev/input/` instead of `/dev/input/by-id`

In my example the correct path is :

```
defenderdz@defenderdz-pc:~$ sudo cat /dev/input/by-id/usb-NOVATEK_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd
���]�I���]�I���]�Ia���]�b���]�b���]�b���]�����]�����]��s���]����]����]����]�>
���]�>
 ���]�>
d���]�8
       ���]�8
              ���]�8
                    ���]�����]�����]��s���]H|���]H|���]H|���]�����]�� ���]��d���]Ǵ���]Ǵ ���]Ǵ
```

In your case

```
neel@pc1$ sudo cat /dev/input/by-id/usb-Plus_More_Enterprise_LTD._USB-compliant_keyboard-event-kbd
```

I'm not saying that it's the best solution but it works fine for me. 
You can even create an automatic detection of the keyboard by parsing the ls result ...

Comment: Aha. It was silly mistake then. Its a 9 year old post. And I don't remember what I was trying to do then. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: hhh, I know, it's more for those who will face this issue (like me), good to see that you're still active in the forum ^^.

Answer (score 15):

Hello,

I was recently trying to accomplish something similar.

Have a look at the logkeys project:

http://code.google.com/p/logkeys/

If you download the source code, and have a look at the logkeys.cc file, you will find one method how to auto-detect which /dev/input/event is used by your keyboard. This will let you read raw scan codes from the keyboard, regardless of which program currently has focus. The logkeys program also shows how to translate the scan codes into characters, and other useful tricks.

Hope this helps,

Markus.

Comment: though the post is old , i want something related to it , if two keyboards are connected how to know from where the input came , in short i want to print the sourceId when any key is pressed ? any leads

Answer (score 15):

A simple `grep` operation on the */proc/bus/input/devices* file will yield all the keyboards plugged into the machine:

```
 grep -E  'Handlers|EV=' /proc/bus/input/devices | \
 grep -B1 'EV=120013' | \
 grep -Eo 'event[0-9]+'
```

Where `EV=120013` is the bitmask for events supported by the device. As explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74903/explain-ev-in-proc-bus-input-devices-data).

This is the way it is implemented in [logkeys](https://code.google.com/p/logkeys/)

Comment: Awesome. Returned event2 for me, and I was able to see data going through on there.

Answer (score 10):

You are reading the wrong device. Either try all /dev/input/event* or look in /var/log/Xorg.0.log for which device is used for your keyboard.

Comment: keyboard is /dev/input/event4 on my fedora box

Comment: keyboard is /dev/input/event3, also symlinked as /dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd  on ubuntu(9.10)

Comment: Ya tested on all all 6 event files.
only event5 was responding and writing some shits on beeps.
Latter I found Its speaker

However probabbly you haven't noticed. I am using USB Keyboard !!!!!

-- EDIT --
`(**) Plus More Enterprise LTD. USB-compliant keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event2"`

But no output in `sudo cat /dev/input/event2`

Answer (score 10):

I'd recommend using the evtest application, it lists all your input devices and allows you monitor their events.

Answer (score 0):

For people coming here to find a way to debug their keyboard-issues: Try using the terminal command `xev`. It displays all the input events your peripherals (keyboard and mouse) emit. Might also prove useful for building a keylogger.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In my tests it haven't captured keyboard events in windows other than that created by the app itself ( the docu says it should ).